# How to get fieldmapping of all indices in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know to the below command is enough throught REST

`get _all/_mapping`

but how to do in java using elastic search api?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543666/how-to-get-type-names-of-elastic-search-index-in-internal-java-api-or-jest-api) shows how to get fieldmaps for single index but the return type is string. we have to JSON parse it and do the work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with the indices admin client like this:

```
    GetMappingsResponse response = client()
        .admin()
        .indices()
        .prepareGetMappings()
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

    ImmutableOpenMap<String, ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData>> mappings = response.getMappings();

    ...
```